# Jmockit not able to return new instance with state in it?

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

Here is mine service method to be tested

```
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
private EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @Override
    public Employee addEmployee(String address) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setAddress(address);

        return employeeDao.create(employee);
    }
}
```

Here is my test class

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class EmployeeServiceImplTest {

    @Tested
    private EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl;

    @Injectable
    private EmployeeDaoImpl employeeDao;

    @Test
    public void testAddEmployee() {
            new Expectations() {{
                Employee employee = new  Employee();
                employee.setAddress("Address1"); //line 1

                employeeDao.create(withInstanceOf(employeeDao.class));
                result = employee;
            }};

            Employee employee=employeeServiceImpl.addEmployee("Address1");
            assertEquals("Address1", employee.getAddress()); // Line 2

}

}
```

But when I do employee.getAddress() at line 2 it returns null. It should return "Address1" as I have set it in expectation at line 1. Why it is returned as null ?

Comment: That's the point I do not want to mock Employee class. Reason is if I mock employee class I won't be able to do `employee.setAddress("Address1")` ?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood what your code was trying to do...

Comment: @ajb Not a problem . Do you have any solution if I want to return new instance with state filled ?

Comment: First of all, there's lots of stuff missing.  `addEmployee` refers to `employeeDao`, but where is `employeeDao`?  You have a method that returns a `CaseNote`, but you haven't told us what the relationship is between `CaseNote` and any other class.  But I think the biggest problem is probably that you're expecting `employeeDao.create(withInstanceOf(employeeDao.class));`, but your tested method calls `employeeDao.create(e)` where `e` is an `Employee`, which is probably *not* an instance of `employeeDao.class`.

Comment: @ajb Its was typo . There is nothing called Note. Its Employee. I have updated both the the stuff you asked

Comment: Surely `employeeDao.class` is a typo, right? You meant `Employee.class`. With this fix, the test works for me (although it still has a few issues: `employee` should be created *outside* the expectation block, and the `employeeDao` field should be of type `EmployeeDao`).

Comment: Ops... although the test does pass (with the fix described in my previous comment), it doesn't really make sense the way it's written, since the assertion is checking the state of an object the test itself created, and which isn't modified by the CUT. The proper way to write this test would remove the `employee` creation in the test, and record the expectation with `result = new Delegate() { Employee create(Employee e) { return e; } };`.

Comment: Conclusion: avoid mocking, it's too easy to write poor/erroneous tests like this; instead, write an integration test which accesses the database (within a rolled-back transaction).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting mocking **wrong**.

The mock that you are creating has **nothing** to do with the "real" class that you are mocking.

In other words: your real class has an "address". And it remembers that when you *set* an address value first, that *getting* the address will return that value you set before.

A mock is just something that "looks" like your class under test. It doesn't have state. It doesn't understand how your setter and getters are related.

In other words: when you put down those expectations, you are describing how the mock will **behave** when methods are invoked on it. Thus change:

```
employee.setAddress("Address1"); //line 1
```

to

```
 employee.getAddress(); result = "Address1";
```

( but I assume the above might not be enough - you really should step back and clearly figure for *yourself* what objects need to be mocked here, and which **behaviour** specifications you need for each of them )

Or again in other words: study the **concepts** you are using **before** applying them. Like in: start reading the [jmockit](http://jmockit.org/) documentation and follow the examples there - instead of inventing your own ideas that have **nothing** to do with how you *should* be using a mocking framework.

Comment: But I did not mock Employee class. This code `employeeDao.create(withInstanceOf(employeeDao.class)); result = employee`   returns  the employee real object not mocked . Is n't it ? Your answer `employee.getAddress(); result = "Address1";` would have been correct if Employee would have been mocked object  which is not the case here.

Comment: JMockit mocks behavior, not state.